# swift remove item from array after `filter` or by finding `firstIndex that `contains`

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, equatable

I have two arrays of `Book`s

```
var tempArray = [Book]()
var filteredArray = [Book]()
```

where

```
struct Book: Codable, Equatable {
    let category: String
    let title: String
    let author: String
}
```

I want to remove a book from `tempArray` if a `title` matches. I can filter `tempArray` searching for `"Some title"` like this

```
filteredArray = tempArray.filter( { $0.title.range(of: "Some Title", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil } )
```

I'm trying this to remove

```
if let i = tempArray.firstIndex(of: { $0.title.contains("Some Title") }) {
        tempArray.remove(at: i)
    }
```

but get this `Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of type '(String)'`. Advice to fix this error? Or alternatively, can the element be removed while filtering?

Comment: I don't understand. A filtered array _has_ removed the unwanted items. That is what filtering _is_. You know how to filter so what is the problem?

Comment: In this case the filtered array contains only the value I want to remove from the original

Comment: @matt as per your suggestion, how can I *reverse* how the filter works? Instead of storing values that match, I would like to store all values that do not match the condition?

Comment: "how can I reverse how the filter works" Use the magic word "not". It's an exclamation mark. For example the opposite of `$0.title.contains("Some Title")` is `!$0.title.contains("Some Title")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. It should be `func firstIndex(where predicate: (Self.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.Index?` instead of `func firstIndex(of element: Book) -> Int?`

```
if let i = tempArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.title.contains("Some Title") }) {
    tempArray.remove(at: i)
}
```

Another option is to use `RangeReplaceableCollection`'s method `mutating func removeAll(where shouldBeRemoved: (Book) throws -> Bool) rethrows`:

```
tempArray.removeAll { $0.title.contains("Some Title") }
```

---

**Playground testing:**

```
struct Book: Codable, Equatable {
    let category, title, author: String
}
```

---

```
var tempArray: [Book] = [.init(category: "", title: "Some Title", author: "")]
print(tempArray)   // "[__lldb_expr_12.Book(category: "", title: "Some Title", author: "")]\n"

tempArray.removeAll { $0.title.contains("Some Title") }
print(tempArray)  //  "[]\n"
```

Comment: I did give that a try. It leaves me with `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'where:', expected 'of:')`, `Replace 'where' with 'of'`

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? It compiles fine here.

Comment: Version 10.2.1 (10E1001).

Comment: still showing the same error as before for me `Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of type '(String)'` :/

Comment: @Andy sorry but I can't reproduce that error. Are you sure te code I posted above is throwing this error ? Can you post a link with a screen shot of it?

Comment: I've adopted your changes and it's working! Instead directly using this line `var tempArray: [Book] = [.init(category: "", title: "Some Title", author: "")]` I was initialising `tempArray` from another VC like `tempArray = BooksController.favouriteBooks`

Comment: I added that line before assigning the values at it worked just fine. thanks very much